# Output of Image recognition as a label in supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to machine learning and I am stuck in understanding something. I want to create a model in which an Image of a car crash/scratch is recognized and then use that Image to measure the speed of the car. I have a good amount of data with car crash images and the related speed to them.

So basically, I want a model to first recognize the car crash in the image and then recognize the speed related to it. I already have a model which recognizes the car crash using CNN but I don't understand how can I proceed further to predict the speed using the crash.

Please suggest me something. I am pretty new to ML.

Comment: So you want to input the localized (segmented) image part to another neural network and predict the car speed based on this localized image? If this is the case output of image recognition is not a "label", instead is an input to the speed prediction neural network?

Comment: Can you explain a little more please. Or share any link if possible.

Comment: @AchinthaIhalage Can you explain me a little more about it please? Thanks.